# Create Bezier curves with random heights that connect

Tags: unity, procedural, curves, beziers

In unity, I am trying to create several curved platforms that connect using bezier curves, however I am having issues. I understand the basics of genertating a bezier curve and I have something working well

My goal is to generate a series of forward moving Bezier curves, that are all connected to each other, while also having varying lengths and points. I have something working, however I am having issues connecting the curves, while retaining random Y values for different heights in the 4 points.

Below is my attempt:
[image: issue]

Below is a Sketch I did in MS Paint to help explain goal:
[image]

From the sketch you can see that there is a diffrence in height between gameobject 0 and 1 but they are still connected. How can I generate the next points with random Y values, while still accounting for the previous curve? Any help would be greatly appreciated,

Thank you for your time.

Comment: I had a similar setup in  a game. What i did was like `gameobject1.P0 = gameobject0.P4` and also `tangent` at `gameobject0.p4` = `tangent` at `gameobject1.p0`. Tangent of the curve is basically the derivative at that point. I don't have the files with me now but you can give it a shot like this

Comment: Why can't you start the generation of the next chunk at the last point of the previous chunk?

Comment: Thank you Nightcrawler23 and jgallant for the help! I was able to figure out the issue but I wanted to say thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's start by declaring a few variables: 
-**p1** is the y value of "Gameobject-0"
-**p2** is the y value of "Gameobject-1"
-**t1** is the height of the last point on the first curve(Gameobject-0)
-**t2** is the height of the first point on the second curve(Gameobject-1)

Having said all this, you should use equation:

```
p2 = p1 + t1 - t2
```

Comment: JasonPH for the help. I didn't use this equation exactly however it did help me get to my answer. I will post it later. Thank you so much for the help